# Limiting users from executing a code more than once a week (not automatic)

Tags: php

I want my users to just have access to executing a script just once a week.
Please note that i don't want the code to be executed once a week 'automatically'.

I want the user to just be able to just execute the code (synchronously) once a week. In the scope, the script i am restricting users from accessing is a scan. thanks...
I tried this but it didn't work.

```
if (isset( $_POST['action'])) {
    switch($_POST['action']){

    $q = mysql_query("SELECT dateStop from `run` where userid = $userid");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q) or die(mysql_error());
    $timeDiff = time() - $row['dateStop'];
    $timeDay = $timeDiff / (24 * 60 * 60);
    if ($timeDiff <= 604800) {
        echo "<script> alert('You can only scan once in a week. Try again in the next $timeDay day(s)'); </script>";

        case "is_running": {
            $res = $db->query("SELECT 1 FROM `" . SQL_PREFIX . "run` WHERE userid = $userid and ISNULL(dateStop)");
            die(json_encode(array("running" => (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0))));
        } else {.....}
```

Comment: what format is your dateStop like is a timestamp, datetime, mon,day,year? Also switch case does not look right syntax

Comment: dateStop is formatted timestamp. its just a snippet though. is timestamp the right format ?

Comment: i would change the format to datetime tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it with **SQL**.

Provide **userid** to the following SQL and **it will let you know** if the User is allowed to Scan or NOT.

```
SELECT IF(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, dateStop) >= 7, 'yes', 'no') AS allowedToScan
FROM `run`
WHERE userid = 2
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b32db6/10

Comment: Consider up-voting this Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a quick script which will do what you want edit it around so it works for you. Read the comments they explain what is being done. Any problems comments and will check it

```
/**
**YOU can use this function to get hold of the date a week from your current date.
**It does generally process most date formats eg. 10-12-2015, jan 28, 2015, timestamp...
**/

function processDate($val, $days)
{
    $value = $val;
    $dayToAdd = $days;

    switch($value)
    {                                   
    case is_numeric($value):
        // time()
        $value = strtotime('+'.$dayToAdd.' days', $value);
        $value = date('d - m - Y', $value);
        break;
    default: 
        // days + Unix
        $value =  strtotime(str_replace(',', '', $value));
        $value = strtotime('+'.$dayToAdd.' days',$value);
        $value = date('d - m - Y', $value);
        break;
    }

    return $value;
}



/**
**Presuming this checks if a button is clicked?
**/

if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
    /**
    **Im presuming this query gets hold of the last date when the script was run.
    **I DID NOT TEST THIS SCRIPT WITH A DB i testing it by setting $row['dateStop'] = time();
    **You will have to test with db.
    **/

    //delete $row['dateStop'] = time() AND UNCOMMENT YOUR QUERY TO TEST IT.
    $row['dateStop'] = time();


    /**
    **UNCOMMENT YOUR QUERY AND TEST SCRIPT USING IT.
    **/

    //$q = mysql_query("SELECT dateStop from `run` where userid = $userid LIMIT 1");    
    //$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q) or die(mysql_error());




    /**LastDate = last date script was run, NewDate = a week after last date, timeDiff = how many days diffrence
    **You can edit the function to get the format to be whatever you need. So if you want it to be like unix
    **timestamp you will have to change date('d - m - Y', $value); INTO a correct format use http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
    **/

    $LastDate = processDate($row['dateStop'], 0);
    $NewDate = processDate($row['dateStop'], 7);
    $timeDiff =  $NewDate-$LastDate;

    /**
    **Correct way to use a switch case to check if either the date is within a week or if it has been a week.
    **/

    switch ($timeDiff) 
    {
    case $timeDiff == 7:
        //code to be executed if it has been a week;
        echo "it has been 7 days".$timeDiff;
        break;
    case $timeDiff > 7:
        //code to be executed if it has been over a week;
        echo "it has been over 7 days".$timeDiff;
        break;
    case $timeDiff<7:
        //code to be executed if it has been less than a week;
        echo "it has been less than 7 days".$timeDiff;
        break;
    default:
        //A default script to run incase none of the cases match;
    }
}
```